# Avoid Symfony forcing form fields display

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a form type, setting 10 fields.
In my twig template, I display 8 fields everytime, and 2 fields inside a condition :

```
{% if computed is not empty %}
    <div class="container-filters">
        <div class="form-group">
             {{ form_row(form.filterStart) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
              {{ form_row(form.filterEnd) }}
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-evo" value="OK" />
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

But no matter if my condition is true or false, Symfony will display those 2 fields. If my condition is true, they will be displayed because of my {{ form_row() }} statement, which is normal behavior. If my condition is false, they will be displayed anyway, because Symfony 2 force form fields to be displayed.

How can I prevent this weird behavior ?

Answer (score 42):

I guess you have a form_end or form_rest somewhere after your presented code.

You can tell to not render remaining fields in the form_end helper :

```
{# don't render unrendered fields #}
{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html

BTW, I would suggest to add your logic in your FormType.

Comment: I can't find how to move this logic into the form type. What's the method to call ? For now, I added {'render_rest': false} into the view, but my validation doesn't pass anymore : "The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form". So the token field didn't generate, pretty normal. Can I add exceptions to thoses remaining fields not displaying ?

Comment: You can render the csrf token manually : {{ form_row(form._token) }}

Answer (score 10):

You can force the items to having been rendered like..

```
{% do form.filterStart.setRendered %}
{% do form.filterEnd.setRendered %}
```

If you are using `{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}` then you should be aware that you would need to render your CSRF token, unless you have specifically turned it off.

Both of these approaches may clear the values on your model due to them not being in the posted data.

Alternatively you can just place the fields in a hidden div, but this is a little hacky (then again the other ways are too).

The best way, as mentioned by Christophe, would be to add this into your form logic.
The way you choose to do this would depend on whether the availability of these fields depends on a predetermined factor or on data coming from the actual model.

**Predetermined**

Your Form Type

```
class YourFormType extends AbstractType
{
    //...

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        //...

        if ($options['your_condition']) {
            $builder
                ->add('filterStart', 'date')
                ->add('filterEnd', 'date')
            ;
        }
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            //...
            'your_condition' => false,
        ));
    }

    //...
}
```

Creating Your Form

```
$form = $formFactory->create(
        // Or $this->createForm if you are using the controller
    'your_form_name', 
    $model, 
    array('your_condition' => true/false)
);
```

**From The Model**

Form Type

```
class YourFormType extends AbstractType
{
    //...

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        //...

        $builder
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) {
                $form = $event->getForm();
                $model = $event->getData();

                if (!$model || 'something' !== $model->getSomething()) {
                    return;
                }

                $form
                    ->add('filterStart', 'date')
                    ->add('filterEnd', 'date')
                ;
            })
        ;
    }

    //...
}
```

Bother of these would then require you to check that the fields had been created when rendering them in your template like..

```
{% if form.filterStart is defined and form.filterEnd is defiend %}
    <div class="container-filters">
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form_row(form.filterStart) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form_row(form.filterEnd) }}
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-evo" value="OK" />
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `FormView->children` has public access you can handle the logic into your controller:

```
if(<condition>) {
    $formView->children['filterStart']->setRendered();
    $formView->children['filterEnd']->setRendered();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have 1 form that you want to display differently on two template you can remove a specific field directly in your Controller:

```
public function firstWayAction()
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new RemoveFormFieldType());

    $form->remove('second');

    // form processing...   
    return $this->render('QADayBundle:RemoveFormField:form.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

See this article for more details:
https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/question-answer-day/remove-form-field

Answer (score 0):

you can set "style=display:none" in your twig.

```
<div style= "display:none">
    {{ form_row(form.filterStart) }}
</div>
```